# Accessing react native StyleSheet member via dynamic key string in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have this stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  primary: {},
  secondary: {},
})
```

And I would like to access the keys with dynamically composed strings.

```
<View style={styles[props.type]}/>
```

This is when TS complains (but the code runs just fine as one would expect):

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ primary: { }; secondary: { }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '...'.ts(7053)
```

How could I nudge TS in the right direction and make it happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the minimal stripped-down working example:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

type Props = {
    type: 'primary' | 'secondary'
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    primary: {},
    secondary: {}
});

const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({ type }) => {
  const style = styles[props.type];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My prop is currently defined as `type: "primary" | "secondary"` and I'd like to keep it that way, would it be possible to convert/cast my type to a "key type"? Also your approach would open all keys of the stylesheet to the outside, which would be leaking to much info to the outside.

Comment: From the error message it seems like it's getting converted to a string along the way. Compare your code to this TypeScript playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZRgTwDYFNkAstbwC+cAZlBCHAERRYCGAxjALQB29MwAbltQNwAoQejBY4ABQpgAznAC8iQXBVxRWAFxwA5GCih6UNNrgAfHTKyMIbACaHjgosOtsZ8d5ixzFqL3gIYADpGOk4sAAoEZVU9AyMtBCIAGhiVS1d7BMRnIgBKIUFXdzg9CFktKXKfJVU1NDEtXX0QB20nFxsSz2wFOB7vAG0y2SD1AF1+IA

Comment: Somehow, it does seem to work now like in your playground example. Would you modify your answer accordingly cause I can't set my `type` to `StyleType` as described in my first comment.

Comment: I guess the only way to make it work with composed key strings is this: `type StyleKey = key of styles; styles[props.type + "Disabled" as StyleKey]`?